# App.js has red background in Titanium Studio. How can I get Titanium to import the project as if it's new?

Tags: titanium

- I have a project that I imported from a shared folder.
- Everything worked fine until the hosting computer restarted
- After the shared folder was back up I restarted Ti Studio, deleted the project, and imported it again, but it still wouldn't allow me to run the app.

Now there is an asterisk next to the project name so it looks like
   this:

```
* ProjectName [master]
```

However, before the connection was lost it said [master + 1].

Also there's an asterisk next to app.js, and the background is red:

[image: app.js has a red background]

When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
 [ERROR] : ** BUILD FAILED ** [ERROR] : The following build commands failed: 
 [ERROR] :   Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/ProjectName normal i386 
 [ERROR] : (1 failure)
```

This application worked before I accidentally lost connection to the host folder.

I have also tried cleaning the project.

It seems like Titanium is trying to recover what I saved during the restart, so it won't allow me to run the project again.

**TL;DR:** How do I make Titanium Studio "forget" this project, and treat it like it's brand new?

**UPDATE**: I tried deleting the project and creating a new one with the same name, now all the files and folders have an asterisk next to them and the files have a red background. Next I'll try a new name...

**UPDATE 2**: Naming the project a new name didn't work either. Next I'll try creating a new project locally.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create the project locally. For some reason, after losing the connection, Titanium couldn't hold a connection to the shared folder.

Edit: Here's what I did to get everything back to normal:

1. I deleted everything locally, on the shared folder, and from the workspace
2. I created the project locally
3. copied it to the shared folder
4. deleted the project from Ti Studio (didn't choose the option to delete the actual files)
5. then imported the project from the shared folder

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in project root folder name it .gitignore

file contents:

```
.DS_Store
/app
/build
/plugins
/Resources
/platform
/i18n
build.log
build
CHANGELOG.txt
DefaultIcon-ios.png
DefaultIcon.png
iTunesConnect.png
LICENCE
LICENCE.txt
Manifest
MarketplaceArtwork.png
README
tiapp.xml
npm-debug.log
tmp
.map
.project
.settings
Thumbs.db
```